# How should I handle variables whose data points have varying degrees of predictive power?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, modeling, neural-networks

I'm trying to determine which type of learning algorithm is best for making predictions on my data. My data set consists of several independent variables, each of which is accompanied by an "indicator" variable that represents the sample size used to acquire its specific value.

Let's say I'm attempting to assign expected future conversion rates to an assortment of web advertisements (conversion rate = orders/clicks). For some ads, I have a lot of specific traffic history to draw from. But for newer ads that have minimal to no traffic history, I need to rely on higher level characteristics. My data set consists of historical conversion rates at different levels/traits of the ad:

[image]

For ad #5, I would want my model to rely almost completely on the historical conversion rate for the specific ad (4.23%) since it has enough past clicks for me to trust that value. For ad #1, however, I would like the model to ignore the "specific ad" value and rely mostly on the historical rates for the "brand" and "product category" of the ad (since 15 clicks is not enough to establish a reliable conversion rate).

I've had some success with separating ads into several different groups by similarity of click volume, then using a different regression formula for each group. This allows each variable to be properly weighted. However, this approach ends up spreading the data too thin and likely does not learn as well as one consolidated model could.

What is a good approach for using one model to make predictions on this data? I need the model to recognize that the "clicks" variables should be used to weight their respective conversion rates accordingly. (I've also had some small success with the nnet package in R, but the results are very hit-and-miss). Please don't hesitate to ask for clarification. Thanks!